# How to authenticate Firebase real time database connection through a service account json when connecting via HTTP for SSE?

Tags: http, go, firebase-realtime-database, streaming, server-sent-events

I am trying to create real time event listeners for firebase real time data base. I am looking to use the official [REST streaming api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming) and use an sse package for Golang.

I am thinking of using [this package](https://github.com/r3labs/sse) and there is a Client type in the package that looks like this:

```
// Client handles an incoming server stream
type Client struct {
    URL               string
    Connection        *http.Client
    Retry             time.Time
    subscribed        map[chan *Event]chan bool
    Headers           map[string]string
    EncodingBase64    bool
    EventID           string
    disconnectcb      ConnCallback
    ResponseValidator ResponseValidator
    ReconnectStrategy backoff.BackOff
    ReconnectNotify   backoff.Notify
    mu                sync.Mutex
}
```

and a new client function that looks like this:

```
// NewClient creates a new client
func NewClient(url string) *Client {
    return &Client{
        URL:        url,
        Connection: &http.Client{},
        Headers:    make(map[string]string),
        subscribed: make(map[chan *Event]chan bool),
    }
}
```

I am thinking about writing a NewClient() function that passes in the authentication for firebase from the service account json. Does anyone know how to do this and what information I would need to pass from the json to where in the request/headers?

Comment: If Firebase uses Auth, then start at https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2/google

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out! I think this is what I need there is an example with a service account, which is what I am using. Thank you!